# InfoPath. Can you edit a View at a time?

Tags: workflow, infopath, view-styles

I've got an InfoPath 2013 form divided into four sections. When the user fills in the first View and it's approved I've set up a Nintex Workflow to send out the next View to be filled in. Great. However when the email is sent and the link is clicked on it opens up the first default view which has already been filled it. I want it to move onto the next View. Any ideas?

Comment: on form load rules you can switch between views

Comment: Cheers, but there may be two to three days before one of the views being filled in so I need to be able to send a link to the View which could be filled in at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden check box/drop down (with Yes and No). On the first view's Submit button, add the rule to change the value of this check box/drop down from no to Yes.

Now on the Form load rule, put the condition on this check box/ drop down, if yes then second view otherwise first view.

Comment: Or add a field that gives a more complete state machine. If there are 4 sections you might need 2 boolean fields or a text field with 4 different states. Also in such a situation I have found it useful to promote the fields to the SP list so you can monitor and manage the states from outside the forms.